# Rails: product is set to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have an ecommerce website with products, carts and other things.

Both variables @produit and @produits are set to nil but i have no idea why.

here is `produit.rb` :

```
class Produit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items

  default_scope { where(active: true) }

  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader

  validates :nom, presence: true
  validates :artisan, presence: true
  validates :quantite, presence: true
  validates :categorie, presence: true
  validates :denomination, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :prix, presence: true
  validates :photo, presence: true

end
```

here is the controller:

```
class ProduitsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @produits = Produit.all
    @order_item = current_order.order_items.new(produit_params)

    if @order_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @order_item, notice: 'Le produit a été ajouté au panier !' }
      format.json { render json: @order_item, status: :created, location: @order_item }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render action: 'create', notice: 'Le produit n\'a pas été ajouté au panier' }
      format.json { render @order_item.errors, status: unprocessable_entity }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def show
    @produit = Produit.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def produit_params
    params.require(:produit).permit(:nom, :quantite, :description, :denomination, :artisan, :categorie, :prix, :photo)
  end

end
```

I also have this view in produits/index :

```
<%= render partial: 'layouts/navbarindex' %>

<%= render partial: 'produits/header' %>


<div id="path-progress-bar">
  <p>Accueil</p>
  <p>/</p>
  <p style="color:black">Boutique de produits breton</p>
</div>

<section id="marche-breton-container">

  <%= render template: 'categories/index' %>

  <div id="produits-column-container">
    <% if @produits %>
      <% @produits.in_groups_of(4, false).each do |g| %>
        <% g.each do |produit| %>
          <%= render partial: "produits/produit_row", produit: @produit, order_item: @order_item %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

</section>
```

and here is the renderer `_produit_row.html.erb` :

```
<div id="produits-row-container">
  <div id="fiche-produit-container">
    <%= form_for order_item, remote: true do |f| %>
      <div id="produit-img">
        <%= link_to produits_show_path do %>
          <%= image_tag produit.photo %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div id="produit-nom">
        <%= produit.nom %>
      </div>
      <div id="produit-prix">
        <%= number_to_currency(produit.prix, unit: '€', format: "%n%u") %>
      </div>
      <div id="produit-au-panier">
        <%= image_tag('icon/icon-panier') %>
        <%= f.submit 'Ajouter au panier' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that `@produit` and `@produits` are set to nil, so the view doesn't display anything even though i have an active_admin session where products are set up.

UPDATE: the `logs`:

```
Started GET "/mon-marche-breton" for ::1 at 2017-05-24 09:17:47 +0200
Processing by MarcheBretonController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_cart_text.html.erb (6.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbarindex.html.erb (26.4ms)
  Rendered produits/_header.html.erb (3.4ms)
  Categorie Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories`
  Rendered categories/index.html.erb (5.5ms)
  Rendered produits/index.html.erb (39.2ms)
  Rendered marche_breton/index.html.erb within layouts/application (40.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (3.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 253ms (Views: 242.1ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)


Started GET "/assets/bg/bg-banner.png" for ::1 at 2017-05-24 09:17:48 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bg/footer.png" for ::1 at 2017-05-24 09:17:48 +0200


Started GET "/assets/bg/before-footer.png" for ::1 at 2017-05-24 09:17:48 +0200
```

Comment: Did you check in the rails console, that `Produit.all` is getting data. Also, the products that you have stored, have the attribute `active: true` ? remember the `default_scope { where(active: true) }`.

Comment: `Produits#index` shouldn't be receiving params for `OrderItem`. It should be a GET request. Consider moving the `@order_item.save` conditional to an `OrderItems` controller (probably in a `create` action).

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla Yes i did check the rails console and `Produit.all` is getting the data i entered in my active_admin session. That's why i don't understand...

Comment: If I'm reading this right, `produits/index.html` is never rendered: if the `order_item` params aren't present, `create` is rendered. If they are present, the request is redirected to `OrderItems#show`.

Comment: @coreyward `produit/index.html.erb` is rendered. Which is not renderer is the partial `produit/_produit_row.html.erb`. I have tried to do what you said but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: @justinedps26 Okay, what action is rendering it? Either the code you're sharing isn't the code you're running or there's no index being rendered. Read the code you wrote…it's redirecting or rendering another action on either fork of the conditional.

Comment: @coreyward in `produit/index.html.erb` i have a partial called inside an each statement. The `produit/index.html.erb` is also called inside a view named `marche_breton/index.html.erb`. It is called as a template rendering. i'm not sure it's clear but i know the issue comes from the `_produit_row.html.erb` partial rendering

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
<% @produits.in_groups_of(4, false).each do |g| %>
        <% g.each do |produit| %>
          <%= render partial: "produits/produit_row", produit: @produit, order_item: @order_item %>
```

You iterate over the collection `@produits` and assign each single instance of the collection to `produit`. Hence when you pass the partial `produit: @produit`  you actually pass `nil`.

To solve this, just remove the `@` and have it scoped properly! :)

```
<% @produits.in_groups_of(4, false).each do |g| %>
        <% g.each do |produit| %>
          <%= render partial: "produits/produit_row", produit: produit, order_item: @order_item %>
```

Besides that I assume that `produits_show_path` in your partial will not work like that. You may want to have it like this:

```
link_to produit_path(produit) do
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: the thing is, `@produits` is also nil. I have tried to do what you just suggested and it doesn't work...

Comment: Oh, okay. First, make sure you definitely have `Produit` in your DB. Besides that, please remove the `if @order_item.save`-part from your index-method (Also remove the else-case) so that you can make sure it's rendering the index-view. I guess due to this conditional it's not actually rendering your desired view.

Comment: `Produit` is in the DB. I have removed the `if @order_item.save` statement (also the `else` case) and nothing changes. I will update the question with the logs to let you see what's happening

Comment: Please try to use `gem pry` to debug this further. Add it to your Gemfile, run `bundle install` and after `@produits = Produit.all` add a new line with `binding.pry`. Your server will then add a breakpoint at that line of code and allow you to debug all variables. Check that `Produit.all` does in fact return items and tell us, what `@produits` evaluates to.